# Restrict SpringCloud Application to one server IP address

Tags: ip, spring-cloud

I have many local IP addresses on my host (Windows):

$ ipconfig | find "IPv4"

- IPv4 address. . . . .: 192.168.55.1
- IPv4 address. . . . .: 10.11.12.38
- IPv4 address. . . . .: 172.16.10.5
- IPv4 address. . . . .: 192.168.87.29

When I start SpringCloud application, it's health on Spring Cloud server (Eureka?) dashborad is unknown. Moreover, on server dashboard it shows my registered service with "192.168.55.1" (this is a first IP from my list, but it is a Virtual Adapter IP address). I suppose, that there is no route from SpringCloud server (Eureka?) to this IP, thats why my service's health is unknown (it cannot ping back service).

I want to restrict my SpringCloud service application to bind only to certain IP addresses (or even masks), f.e. only 10.X.X.X network. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply set your `eureka.instance.hostname` to the IP address that you want to bind to. This is probably the easiest. Another (with Brixton snapshots) is to configure a pattern for the name of the network adapter you want to bind to.

Comment: Well, I'd like to specify some kind of net mask, f.e. 10.255.255.255/32 or something like this, not exact IP address

Comment: I guess the network interface name might work then? The mask is an interesting idea for a new feature in `InetUtils`. If this is for local development I expect "localhost" will work just fine as well.

Comment: As far as I undertstod from here (http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html, topic "Ignore Network Interfaces"), this allows me to filter network interface names, not IPs.

Comment: I want to get some flexibility (filter IPs, masks, their priorities), to be able to deploy application WITHOUT CHANGING THIS SETTINGS on local host (f.e. 192.168.11.5) and on the server (f.e. 192.168.11.1). I see it like some kind of preference like this: my.server.preferredHosts=10.0.255.0/32,192.168.1.0/32,192.168.11.0/32   where order does matter

Comment: I don't really understand how that would work, but please open an issue in spring-cloud-commons and we can discuss it there if you like.

Comment: Created issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/88